# CakePHP: Create clickable URL from output in View

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

My edit.ctp form includes a field for the user to enter a URL. In my View, I need to take the supplied URL for each line item and turn it into a clickable link. The link text should just be "Link".

Here is a sample of the static output:

```
<?php foreach($lineitems as $lineitem) { ?>
    <td><?php echo h($lineitem['LineItem']['web_address']); ?></td>
<?php } ?>
```

How can I make my web_address field clickable for each line item?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. Simplicity itself, apparently:

```
<?php foreach($lineitems as $lineitem) { ?>
    <td><?php echo $this->Html->link($lineitem['LineItem']['web_address'], array('target'=>'_blank')); ?></td>
<?php } ?>
```